# Retreive upper heirarchy

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I have Categories stored in a single table.

```
id  name    parentId    path    
A1  Cat 1   0           Cat 1
A2  Cat 2   A1          Cat 1 > Cat 2
A3  Cat 3   A2          Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3
A4  Cat 4   A3          Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4
A5  Cat 5   A4          Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4 > Cat 5
A6  Cat 6   A5          Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4 > Cat 5 > Cat 6
```

I want to fetch all the upper hierarchy till I reach parent category id.

What I have achieved so far is:

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parentId, path) AS (
    select
        id,
        name,
        parentId,
        path
    from
        categories
    where
        parentId = 'A3'
    union
    all
    select
        c.id,
        c.name,
        c.parentId,
        c.path
    from
        categories c
        inner join cte on c.parentId = cte.id
)
select
    *
from
    cte;
```

Now the issue with above query is that I gives me lower hierarchy:

```
id  name    parentId    path
A4  Cat 4   A3  Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4
A5  Cat 5   A4  Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4 > Cat 5
A6  Cat 6   A5  Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 3 > Cat 4 > Cat 5 > Cat 6
```

But what I am expecting is this:

```
id  name    parentId    path
A2  Cat 2   A1          Cat 1 > Cat 2
A1  Cat 1   0           Cat 1
```

I have created a reproducible scenario:

https://dbfiddle.uk/D3czXMX4

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse the direction of the relationship in your join and start with id instead of parentId -

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parentId, path) AS (
    select
        id,
        name,
        parentId,
        path
    from
        categories
    where
        id = 'A3'
    union
    all
    select
        c.id,
        c.name,
        c.parentId,
        c.path
    from
        categories c
        inner join cte on c.id = cte.parentId
)
select
    *
from
    cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/re0Atgdn)

Comment: I dont want the A3 record

Comment: So just skip it in your result processing! Until you retrieve A3 you don't know who its parent is. Alternatively, if you already know the parent id you want to start from, pass it into the cte. Or `order by id desc limit 1, 100`